# Regular expression for Japanese, English hashtag like Twitter

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, cjk

Currently, I'm using this regular expression to detect Japanese hashtag and English hashtag.

`\B([#＃][·・ー_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚぁ-んァ-ン一-龠]{1,24})(?=\W|$)`

The rule is:

```
Hashtag must be started with # character.
Hashtag will be detected by space character and other special characters (!,@,&,*,%,$).
Example 1: Hello#guys. This is a #test. -> Valid hashtag: #test.
Example 2: Hello#guys. This is a #test!#message. -> Valid hashtag: #test and #message
Example 3: Hello#guys. This is a #test #message. -> Valid hashtag: #test and #message
Example 4: Hello#guys. This is a #test#message. -> Valid hashtag: #test
Example 5: #asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd -> Valid hashtag: none
Example 6: # -> Valid hashtag: none
```

It works so far until I met these 2 specific cases with Japanese characters :(

**#日本語#asd** => Valid hashtag should be **#日本語**

**#日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語** => Will not a valid hashtag

The regular expression above cant detect these 2 cases, I try a lot of ways but not find any solution so far.

Currently, I'm using this site for testing: https://regexr.com/

Please help, thanks in advance.

---

Thanks to **@Ryszard Czech**

The final solution will be, this will work exactly like Twitter hashtag:

`/(?<![\p{L}0-9ー_])([#＃][一_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ一-龠ぁ-ゔァ-ヴ]{1,24})(?![\p{L}0-9ー_])/gu`

Test: https://regex101.com/r/Goaqqs/1

Comment: I tried. I only managed the 2nd case.

\B([#＃][·・ー_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚぁ-ゔァ-ンｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ一-龯々〆〤]{1,24})(?=[^·・ー_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚぁ-ゔァ-ンｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ一-龯々〆〤]|$)

because japanese characters are considered "non-word", therefore \B and |W doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Unicode properties, you can redefine the `\B` pattern as `(?<![\p{L}0-9])` and the lookahead at the end as `(?![\p{L}0-9])` and use

```js
/(?<![\p{L}0-9])[#＃][·・ー_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚぁ-んァ-ン一-龠]{1,24}(?![\p{L}0-9])/gu
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Goaqqs/1)

**JavaScript snippet**

```js
const string = "Hello#guys. This is a #test. Hello#guys. This is a #test!#message. Hello#guys. This is a #test #message. Hello#guys. This is a #test#message. #asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd #日本語#asd #日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語";
console.log(string.match(/(?<![\p{L}0-9])[#＃][·・ー_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚぁ-んァ-ン一-龠]{1,24}(?![\p{L}0-9])/gu));
```

If the regex in your case does not work with lookbehind and `\p{L}` use:

```js
var string = "Hello#guys. This is a #test. Hello#guys. This is a #test!#message. Hello#guys. This is a #test #message. Hello#guys. This is a #test#message. #asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd #日本語#asd #日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語";
var pL= "A-Za-z\\u00AA\\u00B5\\u00BA\\u00C0-\\u00D6\\u00D8-\\u00F6\\u00F8-\\u02C1\\u02C6-\\u02D1\\u02E0-\\u02E4\\u02EC\\u02EE\\u0370-\\u0374\\u0376\\u0377\\u037A-\\u037D\\u037F\\u0386\\u0388-\\u038A\\u038C\\u038E-\\u03A1\\u03A3-\\u03F5\\u03F7-\\u0481\\u048A-\\u052F\\u0531-\\u0556\\u0559\\u0561-\\u0587\\u05D0-\\u05EA\\u05F0-\\u05F2\\u0620-\\u064A\\u066E\\u066F\\u0671-\\u06D3\\u06D5\\u06E5\\u06E6\\u06EE\\u06EF\\u06FA-\\u06FC\\u06FF\\u0710\\u0712-\\u072F\\u074D-\\u07A5\\u07B1\\u07CA-\\u07EA\\u07F4\\u07F5\\u07FA\\u0800-\\u0815\\u081A\\u0824\\u0828\\u0840-\\u0858\\u08A0-\\u08B4\\u0904-\\u0939\\u093D\\u0950\\u0958-\\u0961\\u0971-\\u0980\\u0985-\\u098C\\u098F\\u0990\\u0993-\\u09A8\\u09AA-\\u09B0\\u09B2\\u09B6-\\u09B9\\u09BD\\u09CE\\u09DC\\u09DD\\u09DF-\\u09E1\\u09F0\\u09F1\\u0A05-\\u0A0A\\u0A0F\\u0A10\\u0A13-\\u0A28\\u0A2A-\\u0A30\\u0A32\\u0A33\\u0A35\\u0A36\\u0A38\\u0A39\\u0A59-\\u0A5C\\u0A5E\\u0A72-\\u0A74\\u0A85-\\u0A8D\\u0A8F-\\u0A91\\u0A93-\\u0AA8\\u0AAA-\\u0AB0\\u0AB2\\u0AB3\\u0AB5-\\u0AB9\\u0ABD\\u0AD0\\u0AE0\\u0AE1\\u0AF9\\u0B05-\\u0B0C\\u0B0F\\u0B10\\u0B13-\\u0B28\\u0B2A-\\u0B30\\u0B32\\u0B33\\u0B35-\\u0B39\\u0B3D\\u0B5C\\u0B5D\\u0B5F-\\u0B61\\u0B71\\u0B83\\u0B85-\\u0B8A\\u0B8E-\\u0B90\\u0B92-\\u0B95\\u0B99\\u0B9A\\u0B9C\\u0B9E\\u0B9F\\u0BA3\\u0BA4\\u0BA8-\\u0BAA\\u0BAE-\\u0BB9\\u0BD0\\u0C05-\\u0C0C\\u0C0E-\\u0C10\\u0C12-\\u0C28\\u0C2A-\\u0C39\\u0C3D\\u0C58-\\u0C5A\\u0C60\\u0C61\\u0C85-\\u0C8C\\u0C8E-\\u0C90\\u0C92-\\u0CA8\\u0CAA-\\u0CB3\\u0CB5-\\u0CB9\\u0CBD\\u0CDE\\u0CE0\\u0CE1\\u0CF1\\u0CF2\\u0D05-\\u0D0C\\u0D0E-\\u0D10\\u0D12-\\u0D3A\\u0D3D\\u0D4E\\u0D5F-\\u0D61\\u0D7A-\\u0D7F\\u0D85-\\u0D96\\u0D9A-\\u0DB1\\u0DB3-\\u0DBB\\u0DBD\\u0DC0-\\u0DC6\\u0E01-\\u0E30\\u0E32\\u0E33\\u0E40-\\u0E46\\u0E81\\u0E82\\u0E84\\u0E87\\u0E88\\u0E8A\\u0E8D\\u0E94-\\u0E97\\u0E99-\\u0E9F\\u0EA1-\\u0EA3\\u0EA5\\u0EA7\\u0EAA\\u0EAB\\u0EAD-\\u0EB0\\u0EB2\\u0EB3\\u0EBD\\u0EC0-\\u0EC4\\u0EC6\\u0EDC-\\u0EDF\\u0F00\\u0F40-\\u0F47\\u0F49-\\u0F6C\\u0F88-\\u0F8C\\u1000-\\u102A\\u103F\\u1050-\\u1055\\u105A-\\u105D\\u1061\\u1065\\u1066\\u106E-\\u1070\\u1075-\\u1081\\u108E\\u10A0-\\u10C5\\u10C7\\u10CD\\u10D0-\\u10FA\\u10FC-\\u1248\\u124A-\\u124D\\u1250-\\u1256\\u1258\\u125A-\\u125D\\u1260-\\u1288\\u128A-\\u128D\\u1290-\\u12B0\\u12B2-\\u12B5\\u12B8-\\u12BE\\u12C0\\u12C2-\\u12C5\\u12C8-\\u12D6\\u12D8-\\u1310\\u1312-\\u1315\\u1318-\\u135A\\u1380-\\u138F\\u13A0-\\u13F5\\u13F8-\\u13FD\\u1401-\\u166C\\u166F-\\u167F\\u1681-\\u169A\\u16A0-\\u16EA\\u16F1-\\u16F8\\u1700-\\u170C\\u170E-\\u1711\\u1720-\\u1731\\u1740-\\u1751\\u1760-\\u176C\\u176E-\\u1770\\u1780-\\u17B3\\u17D7\\u17DC\\u1820-\\u1877\\u1880-\\u18A8\\u18AA\\u18B0-\\u18F5\\u1900-\\u191E\\u1950-\\u196D\\u1970-\\u1974\\u1980-\\u19AB\\u19B0-\\u19C9\\u1A00-\\u1A16\\u1A20-\\u1A54\\u1AA7\\u1B05-\\u1B33\\u1B45-\\u1B4B\\u1B83-\\u1BA0\\u1BAE\\u1BAF\\u1BBA-\\u1BE5\\u1C00-\\u1C23\\u1C4D-\\u1C4F\\u1C5A-\\u1C7D\\u1CE9-\\u1CEC\\u1CEE-\\u1CF1\\u1CF5\\u1CF6\\u1D00-\\u1DBF\\u1E00-\\u1F15\\u1F18-\\u1F1D\\u1F20-\\u1F45\\u1F48-\\u1F4D\\u1F50-\\u1F57\\u1F59\\u1F5B\\u1F5D\\u1F5F-\\u1F7D\\u1F80-\\u1FB4\\u1FB6-\\u1FBC\\u1FBE\\u1FC2-\\u1FC4\\u1FC6-\\u1FCC\\u1FD0-\\u1FD3\\u1FD6-\\u1FDB\\u1FE0-\\u1FEC\\u1FF2-\\u1FF4\\u1FF6-\\u1FFC\\u2071\\u207F\\u2090-\\u209C\\u2102\\u2107\\u210A-\\u2113\\u2115\\u2119-\\u211D\\u2124\\u2126\\u2128\\u212A-\\u212D\\u212F-\\u2139\\u213C-\\u213F\\u2145-\\u2149\\u214E\\u2183\\u2184\\u2C00-\\u2C2E\\u2C30-\\u2C5E\\u2C60-\\u2CE4\\u2CEB-\\u2CEE\\u2CF2\\u2CF3\\u2D00-\\u2D25\\u2D27\\u2D2D\\u2D30-\\u2D67\\u2D6F\\u2D80-\\u2D96\\u2DA0-\\u2DA6\\u2DA8-\\u2DAE\\u2DB0-\\u2DB6\\u2DB8-\\u2DBE\\u2DC0-\\u2DC6\\u2DC8-\\u2DCE\\u2DD0-\\u2DD6\\u2DD8-\\u2DDE\\u2E2F\\u3005\\u3006\\u3031-\\u3035\\u303B\\u303C\\u3041-\\u3096\\u309D-\\u309F\\u30A1-\\u30FA\\u30FC-\\u30FF\\u3105-\\u312D\\u3131-\\u318E\\u31A0-\\u31BA\\u31F0-\\u31FF\\u3400-\\u4DB5\\u4E00-\\u9FD5\\uA000-\\uA48C\\uA4D0-\\uA4FD\\uA500-\\uA60C\\uA610-\\uA61F\\uA62A\\uA62B\\uA640-\\uA66E\\uA67F-\\uA69D\\uA6A0-\\uA6E5\\uA717-\\uA71F\\uA722-\\uA788\\uA78B-\\uA7AD\\uA7B0-\\uA7B7\\uA7F7-\\uA801\\uA803-\\uA805\\uA807-\\uA80A\\uA80C-\\uA822\\uA840-\\uA873\\uA882-\\uA8B3\\uA8F2-\\uA8F7\\uA8FB\\uA8FD\\uA90A-\\uA925\\uA930-\\uA946\\uA960-\\uA97C\\uA984-\\uA9B2\\uA9CF\\uA9E0-\\uA9E4\\uA9E6-\\uA9EF\\uA9FA-\\uA9FE\\uAA00-\\uAA28\\uAA40-\\uAA42\\uAA44-\\uAA4B\\uAA60-\\uAA76\\uAA7A\\uAA7E-\\uAAAF\\uAAB1\\uAAB5\\uAAB6\\uAAB9-\\uAABD\\uAAC0\\uAAC2\\uAADB-\\uAADD\\uAAE0-\\uAAEA\\uAAF2-\\uAAF4\\uAB01-\\uAB06\\uAB09-\\uAB0E\\uAB11-\\uAB16\\uAB20-\\uAB26\\uAB28-\\uAB2E\\uAB30-\\uAB5A\\uAB5C-\\uAB65\\uAB70-\\uABE2\\uAC00-\\uD7A3\\uD7B0-\\uD7C6\\uD7CB-\\uD7FB\\uF900-\\uFA6D\\uFA70-\\uFAD9\\uFB00-\\uFB06\\uFB13-\\uFB17\\uFB1D\\uFB1F-\\uFB28\\uFB2A-\\uFB36\\uFB38-\\uFB3C\\uFB3E\\uFB40\\uFB41\\uFB43\\uFB44\\uFB46-\\uFBB1\\uFBD3-\\uFD3D\\uFD50-\\uFD8F\\uFD92-\\uFDC7\\uFDF0-\\uFDFB\\uFE70-\\uFE74\\uFE76-\\uFEFC\\uFF21-\\uFF3A\\uFF41-\\uFF5A\\uFF66-\\uFFBE\\uFFC2-\\uFFC7\\uFFCA-\\uFFCF\\uFFD2-\\uFFD7\\uFFDA-\\uFFDC";
var results=[], m;
var rx = new RegExp("([" + pL + "0-9])?([#＃][·・ー_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚぁ-んァ-ン一-龠]{1,24})(?![" + pL + "0-9])(?:#[^#\\s]+)*", "g");
while (m = rx.exec(string)) {
    if (m[1] == undefined) results.push(m[2]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the limitations of the Javascript regex engine.  When I used your regex and text in Perl, everything matched as you expected.  When I tried it on regexr.com, I got the erroneous matches.  Doing a few tests, it doesn't recognize kanji as a word character and it seems `\B` is broken.

If you just try matching `\w` and `\W` you'll see what it considers a word and non-word.

If you replace `#日本語#asd` with `#日本語x#asd` it will exclude the `#asd`.  `語#` are both considered non-word characters so `\B` matches.

If you try matching `.\B.` and `.\b.` you'll see all the character pairs that it considers in continuity and not in continuity.  But be aware you need to try it with the line having an even number of characters so do pre and post padding to see all the combinations.
e.g. `foo`  `foo` `foo`

I think the only way to fix the `\B` behavior is to use a negative look-behind but that site doesn't support it.

If you replace the `\W` with `[^·・ー_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚぁ-んァ-ン一-龠]`, it will exclude the too long match.

My advice would be to do this in Perl.  It has the absolute best regular expressions.

Here is the documentation. [Perl Regular Expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Here is what I did in Perl.

```perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

our @s = split /\n/, 
'Hello#guys. This is a #test.
Hello#guys. This is a #test!#message.
Hello#guys. This is a #test #message.
Hello#guys. This is a #test#message.
#asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd 27
# 
#日本語#asd
#日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語 27
#日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語 24
#日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語x 25
';

our $re = qr{\B([#＃][·・ー_0-9０-９a-zA-Zａ-ｚＡ-Ｚぁ-んァ-ン一-龠]{1,24})(?=\W|$)};

foreach my $s (@s) {
  print "String \"$s\":\n";
  print join "\n", ($s =~ m/$re/g), "";
  print "\n";
}
```

Which prints:

```
String "Hello#guys. This is a #test.":
#test

String "Hello#guys. This is a #test!#message.":
#test
#message

String "Hello#guys. This is a #test #message.":
#test
#message

String "Hello#guys. This is a #test#message.":
#test

String "#asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd 27":

String "# ":

String "#日本語#asd":
#日本語

String "#日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語 27":

String "#日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語 24":
#日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語

String "#日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語日本語x 25":
```

HTH

(I deleted my first answer because I realized it was wrong.)

Comment: thanks for your help, i came to this solution

`(?<![ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ一-龠ぁ-ゔァ-ヴーａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９])(?<!\w)[#＃](\w|[ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ一-龠ぁ-ゔァ-ヴーａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９]){1,24}(?=\W|$)(?![ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ一-龠ぁ-ゔァ-ヴーａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９])`

Comment: but the solution of @Ryszard Czech looks neatly so i will follow him :D

Comment: @little_Friend Either way fixing `\B` with the negative look behind was the answer. :)